# Масштабирование изображения в ImageView

Tags: java, android

Добавил картинку в imageView ,но она слишком маленькая.Как изменить размер самой картинки ,не трогая размеры imageView?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вам нужно использовать параметр `scaleType` со значениями `centerInside` или `centerCrop`
Пример:

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/titleIcon"
    android:layout_width="25dp"
    android:layout_height="25dp"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_send"
    android:scaleType="centerInside" />
```